# Help on where I can ask for help regarding the clarification of a software license

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask for help to get help on using a software? I have read the software license but I would like to know if I understood correctly. Where can I ask this?

If you want I can show my full question for more context.

### Update

This is my question:

> I am currently using the "text editor" (so to speak) tinymce. And I'm
> building an open source project that I plan to upload to github once I
> finish it. My project is basically like wordpress (not literally a
> wordpress 2) but you can write notes, and other texts that require
> TinyMCE. And what I want is for my project to work even without
> internet, but I don't know how to do it since TinyMCE by default gives
> you an API that needs you to have internet to work. First I thought of
> copying the javascript that the TinyMCE API returns, but obviously
> before doing that I went to see the license to see how I can use the
> software. My program is going to be like a reminder or a calendar (I
> am not speaking literally) that is, it is going to be a private
> service for the user but that the user could install on his computer.
>
> So it seems to me that the self-hosted application license would
> apply. Although I have already read the license, I do not fully
> understand it. And in something so important I would like someone to
> tell me if I understood correctly, in section 2.3 I understand that I
> can make a copy if I need it but NOT in production, but then if a user
> does not have internet and that copy is needed, it could I use it? I
> hope I have explained myself correctly.

Comment: If the software is open source, then it seems the [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) site will likely be a good place to ask. Nonetheless, if it's applicable, you should first check their [Help Center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help) before possibly posting any questions there. As for showing your "full question for more context", that's a good idea, e.g., so it'll indicate whether or not my suggestion has any merit or use for your case.

Comment: Check out law stackexchange.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I already edited my question and added the question I want to ask, and thanks for the suggestions :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [TinyMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) is open-source software licensed under the [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License), your extension to it will also be open-source, and you want to clarify an aspect of the self-hosted application license, then the first site I suggest you consider is [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/), with its [Topics](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page specifically including "understanding, applying, and complying with Free & Open licenses". Note that a couple of tags to check into (e.g., for duplicates), and possibly use, include [licensing](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) and [MIT](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mit).

However, because you're concerned about an interpretation of a legal document, i.e., the license, then as suggested in [whoisit's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384677/help-on-where-i-can-ask-for-help-regarding-the-clarification-of-a-software-licen#comment1283208_384677), another site to look into is [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/), with its [Topics](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page stating that "Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory" is on-topic. The only relevant tag I could find to check on is [licensing](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing), but you should investigate yourself to see if there are any other ones.

Last, but not least, if this issue is important enough to you, and you want to have strong confidence that all of the relevant legal aspects have been dealt with, I suggest you use the services of an appropriate legal professional.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, right now I will go to those sites and try to see how they work and possibly ask my question there :D.